# How to set my tcsh prompt to show the execution time of the previous command?

Tags: csh, tcsh

I am using tcsh at work and would really appreciate knowing how long the execution of a command took place.

For example:

```
~
❯ sleep 55

~ took 55s
❯
```

Comment: You might be able to hack something together with the `precmd` and `postcmd` special aliases. Or you can use `time sleep 55`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Just use the [time](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command.</s>

```
> time sleep 55
0.001u 0.000s 0:55.01 0.0%  0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

**EDIT:**

I hadn't noticed the title. To do that for every command, you can use the [precmd, postcmd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) aliases along with the [date](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command

```
alias postcmd 'set start_time=`date +%s`'
alias precmd 'set end_time=`date +%s`; @ cmd_time= $end_time - $start_time; echo took $cmd_time seconds'
```

Run both these commands, or add them to ~/.cshrc if you want this to be default behavior. The output would be like this:

```
> time sleep 55
took 55 seconds
```

**Explanation:**

`postcmd`: Runs before each command gets executed.

`precmd`: Runs just before each prompt is printed (after the command runs).

`date +%s`: Prints time in raw seconds format.

I simply saved the raw seconds value in the variables `start_time` and `end_time`, then saved the difference in `cmd_time` and printed it.